# Image Caption Shortcode Broken upon update

Tags: shortcode

I have the following code which I use on my WordPress site:

```php
function ced_get_featured_image_caption()
{
    $get_description = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt;
    if (!empty($get_description)) { //If description is not empty show the div
        echo '<div class="featured\\\_caption">' . $get_description . '</div>';
    }
}
```

Upon updating, however, I can no longer save `functions.php` where I must insert this after each update as I now get a "scrape nonce check failed. please try again." error. I have tried to disable all plugins as they were indicated in my google searching for causing this error, but it persists even with everything disabled. I am not a programmer, and thus am struggling to understand what broke.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: there is nothing in that code that references nonces or scraping, can you fix the formatting of the code in your question? I've wrapped it in the triple back ticks so it knows that it's code but there is no indenting and everything is on a single line so it's super difficult to read

Comment: There. I think it's been fixed. Apologies

Comment: Unfortunately, that nonce check is likely unrelated to the provided code. I'm not finding much on the issue apart from trying to clear any and all caches/cookies related to the site, including any which your host might provide.